# Active Bundles of Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, bundles

I'm trying to show a menu of my Bundles, but I need show only the Bundles that are active, how can I get the active Bundles in Twig?

Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of bundle is stored in the kernel.

You have to create a twig extension `BundleExtension` and pass the kernel as dependency:

```
<?php 

namespace MyBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class BundleExtension extends \Twig_Extension 
{

    protected $kernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @see Twig_Extension::getFunctions()
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'getBundles' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getBundles', array($this, 'getBundles')),
        );
    }

     public function getBundles()
     {
        return $this->kernel->getBundles();
     }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @see Twig_ExtensionInterface::getName()
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'get_bundles';
    }
}
```

Register it as a service:

```
services:
    bundle_extension:
        class: MyBundle\Twig\Extension\BundleExtension
        arguments: ['@kernel']
        tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
```

And now in your twig template:

```
{% set bundles = getBundles() %}
{% for bundle in bundles %}
    {{ bundle.getName()}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: FYI: `{{ bundle.name }}` would do the same as `{{ bundle.getName() }}`.